# Ruby on Rails: skip adding mini_racer to the bottom of the gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `rails generate react_on_rails:install` is adding the `mini_racer` gem to the bottom of my gemfile. I don't want rails to do this because I already have `mini_racer` added to my gemfile.

Is there a global way to disable this functionality, or a flag I can pass in to the rails cli?

I am using Rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an option to make the rails generator skip adding `mini_racer` to my `Gemfile` so I ended up using bash to restore my `Gemfile` back to how it was before I ran the generator:

```sh
cp Gemfile tmp/__ && rails generate react_on_rails:install && mv tmp/__ Gemfile
```